Tek-Hunters from Necromunda: Hive Secundus box
Couple of friends and myself bought Necromunda: Hive Secundus box and each took one faction from the starters. I got the Van Saars. I've almost gone insane assembling the gunntek with long las as my first ever mini. Then I took a break and dove into the rules. Ok, now I learned that I can take only one special at the gang creation. Then why do tek-hunters have several, aren't they supposed to be a starter gang?
We decided on a 1250 credits gang buy, but now I'm confused as to what I can even do with my current set of Tek-Hunters. Can I use them for my gang as they are now? We will be running a modified campaign and I could just write down on the cards the actual gang cast, even if stats/gear is not matching the minis exactly, but how do I even begin? Do I need to order another Van Saars' box so that we can begin our campaign?

While organized play at events like Warhammer World require each model to accurately represent its entry in your gang (WYSIWYG), it's quite common to play without this rule in casual or home settings.
It can be much more fun to play with things like a kit-bash, or practical to say something like "This Genestealer Cult Neophyte counts as an Orlock with a Boltgun" in order to fill in a missing model.
If you're playing with friends check with them about how they'd like to play and adjust accordingly, if they're happy to have you use models built for a higher credit list, or future upgrades then just make sure you have a way of telling what's what and continue building as is (really this will provide everyone else a slight advantage as they'll know which direction you gang is heading).
As for why the box would come with more options, the limitation of only one fighter with a special weapon at gang creation is specific to campaign play. In a campaign, this rule is designed to maintain balance at the start and ensure that gangs have room to grow over time.
In skirmish or one-off games (and other non-campaign games), you usually have more flexibility in how you build your gang. So, if you're playing a skirmish game for fun or practice, you can outfit multiple fighters with special weapons without worrying about the usual gang creation limitations found in campaigns.
